# git command-line multi-factor authentication

Tags: git, github, multi-factor-authentication

I have set up my github account to use a hardware device for multi-factor authentication. However, I just ran git push from the command line and it asked for a username/password. I provided same. SEVERAL TIMES. I had to get it right at least once. Every time, no joy. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Perhaps you need to enable another method for command line use. Like a certificate authentication

Answer (score 4):

Stupid me. Read the fine manual. I quote

"You can create a personal access token and use it in place of a password when performing Git operations over HTTPS with Git on the command line or the API.

"A personal access token is required to authenticate to GitHub in the following situations:

"When you're using two-factor authentication..."

Apologies for hurting the signal-to-noise ratio.